# Navigation drawer not working tutsplus tutorial

Tags: android

trying to implement navigation drawer using tutsplus tutorial but the navigation drawer is not working. The toggle button is not showing .Implementing drawer layout using two variable mDrawerLayout and mActionBarDrawToggle.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawToggle;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActionBarDrawToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {


            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opened);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);

            }


        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawToggle);


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }



    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActionBarDrawToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        return mActionBarDrawToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is that you are not providing `ActionBarDrawerToggle` your toolbar.**

See this line in your code

```
mActionBarDrawToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed);
```

You should pass your toolbar as an argument like below

```
mActionBarDrawToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed)
```